# Flask get a multi-dimensional array posted to it as an array

Tags: python, reactjs, http, flask, stringify

Note: Using Flask & Reactjs

I'm currently struggling with a bug where I'm posting a 3-d array from my frontend to my backend and I'm trying to retrieve it using request.form.get('array',type=list), but it ends up being recieved as a 1d array.

Frontend:

```
let data = new FormData();
this.array = [[[1,4],[2,4]],[[3,1],[2,4]],[[7,4],[1,1]]]
data.append("array", this.array);
return axios
      .post(this.url+`/post_arr`, data, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
      })
      .then((res) => {console.log('hi')
        })
        
      })  }
```

backend:

```
@app.route('/post_arr',methods=['POST'])
def test():
print(request.form.get('array',type=list))
>['1','4','2','4','3','1','2','4','7','4','1','1']
```

Rather than retrieving the array as a 3-d array, it retrieves it as a flattened 1d array, which is not ideal. Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you append a multidimensional array to the javascript `formData` object, it will get automatically transformed into a flattened string.

What you need in javascript is:

```js
let data = new FormData();
this.array = [[[1,4],[2,4]],[[3,1],[2,4]],[[7,4],[1,1]]];
data.append("array", JSON.stringify(array));
```

Then in flask:

The [`getlist`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.getlist) method is what you're looking for.

Try the following:

```py
array = request.form.getlist('array')
```

if it returns in a string like this `['[[[1,4],[2,4]],[[3,1],[2,4]],[[7,4],[1,1]]]']`, simply get the list using the first index: `array[0]`

should return

```
[[[1,4],[2,4]],[[3,1],[2,4]],[[7,4],[1,1]]]
```

Comment: for some reason it's returning the same flattened array. Not sure what's going on...

Comment: @S1534 I updated the answer - try again now :)